# Как при тестировании одного метода вызвать внутри другой метод

Tags: java, junit, mockito, mock

Есть конвертер из сущности в бизнес-объект. В момент конвертации, внутри метода для дозаполнения недостающих полей по `id`, полученному из бизнес-объекта, запрашивается сущность `TaskTypeEntity` методом `taskTypeEntityRepository.get(valueObject.getId())`.

```
@Component
public class TaskTypeConverter implements Converter<TaskTypeEntity, TaskType> {

    @Autowired
    private Repository<Long, TaskTypeEntity> taskTypeEntityRepository;

    @Override
    public TaskTypeEntity toEntity(TaskType valueObject) {
        if (valueObject == null)
            return null;
        else {
            TaskTypeEntity taskTypeEntity = taskTypeEntityRepository.get(valueObject.getId());
            return new TaskTypeEntity(
                    valueObject.getId(),
                    taskTypeEntity.getProject_id(),
                    valueObject.getWorkFlow().getId(),
                    valueObject.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Можно ли и если да, то как реализовать тестирование метода `toEntity()`?
Ведь для полноценного теста надо внутри тестируемого метода `toEntity()`, через вызов `taskTypeEntityRepository.get(valueObject.getId())`, получить сущность `TaskTypeEntity`.
То есть, в момент выполнения `toEntity()` надо определить, что вызывается `taskTypeEntityRepository.get(valueObject.getId())` и подсунуть сущность `TaskTypeEntity`.

```
@SpringBootTest
class TaskTypeConverterTest {

    @Autowired
    private Converter<TaskTypeEntity, TaskType> converter;

    @Test
    void toEntity() {
        // здесь реализация теста
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно, вам нужно замокать зависимость Repository

Должно получиться что-то вроде этого:

```
@SpringBootTest
class TaskTypeConverterTest {

    @Autowired
    private Converter<TaskTypeEntity, TaskType> converter;

    @MockBean
    Repository<Long, TaskTypeEntity> repositoryMock;

    @Test
    void toEntity() {
       TaskTypeEntity taskEntityFake = // создаете ваш объект у которого будет project_id = 100500
       Mockito.when(repositoryMock.get(123)).thenReturn(taskEntityFake);

       TaskType taskType = // создаете ваш параметр у которого будет id=123
       TaskTypeEntity result = converter.toEntity(taskType);

       Assert.assertEquals(100500, result.getProject_id());
    }
}
```